# How can I change the text of WooCommerce Bookings "Book now" button?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am learning more and more php as i go along. I sorta get the gist of how php hooks work (actions, filters)

I was attempting to add a filter to my child functions page:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_booking_single_check_availability_text', 'wc_change_button_text');

function wc_change_button_text() {
      return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use WooCommerce filter hooks to change these, but I wouldn't recommend it because it'll take too long and create code bloat.

Here's what I would recommend: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you may have already found a solution, but for anyone else that stumbles across this post, simply add this snippet to your child theme's functions file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 
'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
   function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
      $button_text = __("Change Text Here", "woocommerce");
      $button = '<a class="book-now button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

      return $button;
}
```

Tested and works 5.4.1